# JSON returned as individual string and not objects

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, jquery

I am using Codeigniter and trying to use the jQuery autocomplete with it. I am also using @Phil Sturgeon client rest library for Codeigniter because I am getting the autocomplete data from netflix. I am return correct JSON and I can access the first element with

```
response(data.autocomplete.autocomplete_item[0].title.short);
```

but when I loop through the results

```
for (var i in data.autocomplete.autocomplete_item) {
 response(data.autocomplete.autocomplete_item[i].title.short)
}
```

it acts like a string. Lets say the result is "Swingers", it will return:
Object.value = s
Object.value = w
Object.value = i

and so on.

the js:

```
$("#movies").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
             url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/welcome/search",
             dataType: "JSON",
             type:"POST",
             data: {
                q: request.term
             },
             success: function(data) { 
                for (var i in data.autocomplete.autocomplete_item) {
                 response(data.autocomplete.autocomplete_item[i].title.short);
                }

             }
          });
       }        
        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            //console.log(item);
        $(ul).attr('id', 'search-autocomplete');
           return $("<li class=\""+item.type+"\"></li>").data( "item.autocomplete", item ).append("<a href=\""+item.url+"\">"+item.title+"</a>").appendTo(ul);
        };
```

the controller:

```
public function search(){
    $search = $this->input->post('q');
    // Run some setup
    $this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'http://api.netflix.com/'));
    // set var equal to results
    $netflix_query = $this->rest->get('catalog/titles/autocomplete', array('oauth_consumer_key'=>$this->consumer_key,'term'=> $search,'output'=>'json'));

    //$this->rest->debug();

    //$json_data = $this->load->view('nice',$data,true);
        //return $json_data;

        echo json_encode($netflix_query);
    }
```

the json return

```
{"autocomplete":
    {"autocomplete_item":[
       {"title":{"short":"The Strawberry Shortcake Movie: Sky's the Limit"}},
       {"title":{"short":"Futurama the Movie: Bender's Big Score"}},
       {"title":{"short":"Daffy Duck's Movie: Fantastic Island"}}
       ...
```

any ideas?
thanks.

there are some console logs with the return
[the url](http://netflix.davidmregister.com)

Comment: also post some of the json response that you are getting

Comment: why do you do json_encode when netflix already returns json? I am not familiar with netflix api but from what i've seen in your question. That just seems wierd to me. Maybe you should just pass netflix repsonse since it is already output as json?

Comment: @Ivan Ivanić i json_encode the response because if I just echo the response or just return it then I get a php error that Object can't be converted to string.

will edit the question to show json return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figured out the correct format that I need to send to the autocomplete response method:
the view

```
$("#movies").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/search", {q: request.term}, 
               function(data){
                    //console.log(data);
                    response(data);

            }, 'json');
   }        
    });
```

the controller:

```
$search = $this->input->post('q');
        // Run some setup
        $this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'http://api.netflix.com/'));
        // Pull in an array
        $netflix_query = $this->rest->get('catalog/titles/autocomplete', array('oauth_consumer_key'=>$this->consumer_key,'term'=> $search,'output'=>'json'),'json');

        $json = array();
        foreach($netflix_query->autocomplete->autocomplete_item as $item){
            $temp = array("label" => $item->title->short);
            array_push($json,$temp);
        }
        echo json_encode($json);
```

what was needed was to send back to the view an array of objects. Thank you guys for all your answers and help!!

Answer (score 0):

`in`, as you've noticed, doesn't do what you'd like with arrays.  Use `$.each`

Comment: I the code to
`$.each(data.autocomplete.autocomplete_item, function(i) {
    response(data.autocomplete.autocomplete_item[i].title.short);
   })`
and i still get the same results

Comment: Well, it should be `$.each(data.autocomplete.autocomplete_item, function(i, item) { response(item.title.short); })`, but clearly, autocomplete_item is a string...

Comment: no dice...it is still looping through the array values as string postions and returning string position. the textbox will have "Swingers" as a search and the autocomplete reads:
S
w
i
n
g
e
r
S

very strange and frustrating behavior...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `for (property in object)` means that you want to access each of its properties rather than accessing them via the index. If you want to access them via the index, you probably want to use the standard `for` loop.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    response(data.autocomplete.autocomplete_item[i].title.short);
}
```

or if you still want to use your code, try this:

```
for (i in data.autocomplete.autocomplete_item) {
    response(i.title.short);
}
```

I haven't test them yet but I think you have the idea.

Comment: no dice...somewhere the loop is return the individual elements instead of the positions. As in the text box would be "Swingers" but the autocomplete looks like
S
w
i
n
g
e
r
s